# Is there a limit on array size in C?

Tags: c, arrays

First of all, [here is my code](https://codeshare.io/ayJ4El) just so that you will be able to keep up.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 10000000

long long min(long long a, long long b, long long c) {

    long long temp_min = a;
    if (b < temp_min) temp_min = b;
    if (c < temp_min) temp_min = c;

    return temp_min;

}

long long numOp (long long n, long long memo[]) {

    memo[1] = 0;

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {

        long long guess_1 = MAX, guess_2 = MAX, guess_3 = MAX;

        guess_1 = memo[i - 1] + 1;

        if (i % 2 == 0) guess_2 = memo[i / 2] + 1;

        if (i % 3 == 0) guess_3 = memo[i / 3] + 1;

        memo[i] = min(guess_1, guess_2, guess_3);

    }

    return memo[n];

}

int main (void) {
    // Read the input from the user
    long long n, v = 0, N;
    scanf ("%lld", &n);
    N = n;

    long long num_operations[n + 1];
    long long sequence[n];

    for (long long i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        num_operations[i] = -1;
    }

    for (long long l = 0; l < n; l++) {
        sequence[l] = -1;
    }

    // Compute the minimum number of operations required to get to n starting form 1
    long long op = numOp (n, num_operations);

    // Print the result
    printf ("%lld\n", op);

    sequence[v++] = n;
    while (n > 1) {

        if (num_operations[n - 1] < num_operations[n]) {

            //printf("%lld ", n - 1);
            sequence[v++] = n - 1;
            n = n - 1;

        } else {

            long long temp1 = -1, 
                      temp2 = -1;

            if (n % 2 == 0) {
                temp1 = num_operations[n / 2];
            } 

            if (n % 3 == 0) {
                temp2 = num_operations[n / 3];
            }

            if (temp2 < temp1) {

                //printf("%lld ", n / 2);
                sequence[v++] = n / 2;
                n = n / 2;

            } else {

                //printf("%lld ", n / 3);
                sequence[v++] = n / 3;
                n = n / 3;

            }
        }
    }

    // Print the intermediate numbers from 1 up through n
    for (long long k = N - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
        if (sequence[k] != -1)
            printf("%lld ", sequence[k]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

So I am working on this problem that has input n such that n is in between 1 and 1,000,000. The program works well on inputs up to 100,000 but as soon as it hits (and even less than) 1,000,000 I get a segmentation fault.

I debugged the program in an effort to narrow down the possibilities and found out that the segmentation fault happens on line 52, on which I try to access an array element.

My only guess is that there exits some kind of limit on how big the array in C can get, if that is the case, do you guys know any way around it ?

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect.

Comment: Yes: it is 42...

Comment: There's no limit in C other than the limit of `size_t`. There's an allocation limit set by your OS (32-bit? 64-bit? `ulimit` settings?).

Comment: The most common problem here is that your allocation returns NULL and you don't check, blindly using it, in which case you step on a land mine and it explodes.

Comment: Your `min` function is also in dire need of some [varargs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic).

Comment: It seems that it was too large to secure on the stack.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I just noticed that. There's no heap allocation here. This is destined to fail when the stack is blown. Solution: `malloc` or something like it.

Comment: I didn't think about using `malloc` here. Thanks for your responses guys, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)s as automatic variables allocated on your [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). So you are limited by the call stack maximal size (often only a few megabytes, details are OS and computer specific).

You should instead allocate these on the heap. Read about [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation). So code instead

```
long long *num_operations = calloc (n + 1, sizeof(long long));
long long *sequence = calloc(n, sizeof(long long));
```

Don't forget to test for failure of `calloc`:

```
if (!num_operations) 
    { perror("num_operations calloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

and likewise for the `calloc` of `sequence`

Don't forget to `free` (e.g. at end of your `main`)

```
free (num_operations);
free (sequence);
```

to avoid [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) (use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to debug these). In your particular case, you might not `free`  since the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of a program (on Linux or Windows, etc...) is deleted when its [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) is ended.

FYI `malloc`, `calloc`, and `free` are using [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), such as [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), to change the virtual address space. But often the C standard library don't release (using `munmap`) `free`-d memory to the OS but marks it as reusable by future `malloc`-s or `calloc`-s.

In practice, you'll better `free` memory as soon as it becomes unneeded (so you often can `calloc` and `free` in the same routine). Reading about [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) techniques, concepts, and terminology is worthwhile.

Of course, heap allocated memory is also limited (since your computer has finite resources), but the limit could depend on the computer and is typically much bigger (at least gigabytes on a laptop, and probably terabytes on supercomputers); sometimes `calloc` appear to work (read about [memory overcommitment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment)) even when resources are exhausted (this is an OS feature I generally disable). On POSIX and Linux systems [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) could be used to lower (or change a bit) that limit.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is as index cannot be larger than the `SIZE_MAX`. But it is not the issue here as you allocate your auto variables on the stack. Stack has a very limited size. You can allocate much more on the heap using the `malloc` family of functions. Of course you are limited by the available for your program heap

Comment: *Stack has a vary limited size. You can allocate much more on the heap using `malloc` family functions.*  That may or may not be true. [For example](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Tuning_and_Optimizing_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_for_Oracle_9i_and_10g_Databases/sect-Oracle_9i_and_10g_Tuning_Guide-Growing_the_Oracle_SGA_to_2.7_GB_in_x86_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_2.1_Without_VLM-Linux_Memory_Layout.html), Linux 32-bit processes have at most 1 GB or so for the `sbrk()` parts of the heap, but up to 2 GB for the stack and the `mmap()` parts of the heap.

Comment: On most linuxem I know stack is limited by default to 8MB. You can check it (and change of course) ulimit -s